# .load not loading fast enough

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a menu hidden when the page first loads and then have to show 850px down the page. It all works pretty well except that when you load www.ripplesofgrace.com the menu flashes really quick. I would like to avoid this. Any suggestions? My code currently is:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(window).load(function(){
         $('#whiteBar').hide();
    });
});

jQuery(function($){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var aTop = $('#whiteBar').height()+850;
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop){
         $('#whiteBar').show();
      } else {
         $('#whiteBar').hide(); 
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you change the CSS style governing the menu? Set its initial visibility property to hidden.

Comment: Use css to hide it

Comment: Putting a "load" handler setup *inside* a jQuery "ready" handler kind-of makes no sense. You can probably just move that `.hide()` call to inside the other initialization handler.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, hide the element with a CSS directive, either inline or in a style sheet.

```
#whiteBar { 
    display: none
}
```

That will give it just about zero chance of being seen before the javascript has a chance to act upon it.

Comment: will the jquery unhide it?

Comment: also if you don't want to lose it's position, use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;`

Comment: @GordonArber, yes. CSS and javascript/jQuery both act on DOM elements. CSS directives  are one-off things that (generally) operate on the initial DOM, as put in place by HTML. Javascript.jQuery (generally) operates in response to later events. Thus, DOM elements are subject to various influences. Whichever influence laughs last, laughs loudest!

Comment: @enzoborgfrantz,  you could indeed do that but not if the element is subsequently to be shown with `.show()`.

Comment: That actually messed up the position of the menu.

@enzoborgfrantz, that canceled out the jQuery that makes it show later

Comment: If you opt for  `visibility: hidden;` then you must use `.css("visibility", "visible");` in jQuery instead of `.show()` in order to make it visible again

Comment: @enzoborgfrantz, I tried that and it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: @GordonArber make sure you aren't using `.hide()` on the element, if you are, use `.css("visibility", "hidden");` instead

Comment: @enzoborgfrantz that was the trick! Thank you so much! (still a newbie at all this)